# Increase the width of pop-up in apex v4.1

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

Is there a quick way to increase the width of Pop-up Item in Oracle Apex.
[image: If Name size increases, it will not be accommodated]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if APEX 4.1 (you should really update to at least 5) has those options.

But the newest one offers the "Width" option under "Appearance" where you can select the amount of characters the field will be wide.

If you want to change the size of the popup window, there is the "Popup Width" property under "Settings".

If none of these options are what you want, or they are not available for your version, you can also just use CSS and change the width of the popup manually like this:

```
.myPopUpClass {
width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Attributes parameter for the modal Page (Page Attributes) to `width="300px"`

Comment: Thanks this worked, style="width:350px;" by entering into HTML Form Element Attributes .

Answer (score 0):

style="width:350px;" by entering into HTML Form Element Attributes